# how a4j:commandbutton determines bean

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

please help me to understand,

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="Age:"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.age}" size="4"/>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Enter Age" reRender="age"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
  <h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText id="age" value="Your age: #{userBean.age}"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

when commandButton is clicked, how it evaluates a bean to call setters for. is it getting refrance from the bean used inside the input area?

thanks

Comment: if the commandbutton has any actionlistener to call then it will call that. otherwise also it does what it suppose to do.

Comment: what is your doubt? like how commandbutton is working???/

Comment: i was actually asking about how it knows to call setter of bean, without having any kind of bean mapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command button does not do that. The command button only determines for itself if an action has to be invoked and if so, which method it is. Each of the input components sets their own value. The actual job is done in the `decode()` method of the `Renderer` associated with the component. During the apply request values phase, JSF walks through all `UIForm`, `UIInput` and `UICommand` components. Each of them first gets the request parameter value by own client ID as request parameter name:

```
String value = request.getParameter(input.getClientId(context));
```

*(the `request` is here [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and `input` is here [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html))*

Then, after a process of conversion and validation where necessary, it get ultimately set as bean property referenced by its own `value` attribute.

```
input.getValueExpression("value").setValue(context.getElContext(), value);
```

The [`ValueExpression#setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object%29) will evaluate the `#{userBean.age}`, auto-create the bean if it doesn't exist in the scope yet and then invoke the `setAge()` method on it with the passed-in value.

This is all in detail described in the [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html).

Comment: it means, when call going out then `#{userBean.age}` calls `setAge()` and when its getting request/re-render it is calling `getAge()` right?

Comment: That's indeed what's happening under the covers.